# how could I add redis in GoLand

Tags: go, redis, goland

I couldn't find the add new redis database options in GoLand IDE,thanks you very mush.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXLck.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

Native Redis support is not implemented yet. Feel free to follow [DBE-283](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-283).

As for now there are some third-party plugins in [Marketplace](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/) to connect Redis from GoLand, please find the most suitable for you, e.g., [this one](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12820-redis).

Answer (score 1):

Native Redis support is implemented now:
https://www.jetbrains.com/go/whatsnew/#databases